# How to use the new EOS account name registered?

Tags: account-name

i registered a EOS account name today which is easy to remember. But how can i use this new account name instead of the old account name randomly generated by the EOSIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you provided the same owner keys for the new account, then just select the new account in scatter or if you are using cleos just load(import) the keys and use new accountname  while doing transaction.

scatter -> identities -> edit(account)-> select the new account.